# Add rows to list of dataframes from another dataframe

Tags: r, list, dplyr

Let's have a list `lis`

```
chicago = data.frame('city' = rep('chicago'), 'year' = c(2018,2019,2020), 'population' = c(100, 105, 110))
paris = data.frame('city' = rep('paris'), 'year' = c(2018,2019,2020), 'population' = c(200, 205, 210))
berlin = data.frame('city' = rep('berlin'), 'year' = c(2018,2019,2020), 'population' = c(300, 305, 310))
bangalore = data.frame('city' = rep('bangalore'), 'year' = c(2018,2019,2020), 'population' = c(400, 405, 410))
lis = list(chicago = chicago, paris = paris, berlin = berlin, bangalore = bangalore)
```

Now I have a new `df` containing latest data for each `city`,

```
df = data.frame('city' = c('chicago', 'paris', 'berlin', 'bangalore'), 'year' = rep(2021), 'population' = c(115, 215, 315, 415))
```

I want to add each row of `df` to `lis` based on `city`.

I do it by,

```
#convert to datframe
lis = dplyr::bind_rows(lis)
#rbind
lis = rbind(lis, df)
#again convert to list
lis = split(lis, lis$city)
```

which is inefficient for large datsets. Is their any **efficient alternate for large datsets**?

Thank you.

## **Edit**

My original list contains `2239` dataframes and dimension of each dataframe is `310x15`.

Estimating execution time,

Best performance by,

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(c(lis, list(df)))[, .(split(.SD, city))]$V1

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min     lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
 av() 823.2123 850.56 933.109 865.7741 921.9321 1268.007   100
```

Next is,

```
lis = dplyr::bind_rows(lis)
#rbind
lis = rbind(lis, df)
#again convert to list
lis = split(lis, lis$city)

Unit: seconds
expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
ac() 1.893728 2.032478 2.323619 2.285914 2.325451 4.304177   100
```

Next,

```
Map(rbind, lis, split(df, df$city)[names(lis)])

Unit: seconds
expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
az() 2.29919 2.444761 2.749236 2.688349 2.887123 4.205997   100
```

Next,

```
imap(lis, ~ .x %>%
                   bind_rows(df %>%
                              filter(city == .y)))
Unit: seconds
expr    min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
ax() 4.9921 5.072752 5.178707 5.121748 5.183845 6.069612   100
```

Comment: Added the `microbenchmark` for all solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `imap` to loop over the `list`, and `filter` the 'df' based on the names of the `list` to append the row in each of the `list` elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
lis2 <- imap(lis, ~ .x %>%
                   bind_rows(df %>%
                              filter(city == .y)))
```

-output

```
> lis2
$chicago
     city year population
1 chicago 2018        100
2 chicago 2019        105
3 chicago 2020        110
4 chicago 2021        115

$paris
   city year population
1 paris 2018        200
2 paris 2019        205
3 paris 2020        210
4 paris 2021        215

$berlin
    city year population
1 berlin 2018        300
2 berlin 2019        305
3 berlin 2020        310
4 berlin 2021        315

$bangalore
       city year population
1 bangalore 2018        400
2 bangalore 2019        405
3 bangalore 2020        410
4 bangalore 2021        415
```

---

Or using `base R` with `Map` and `rbind`

```
Map(function(x, nm) rbind(x, df[df$city == nm,]), lis, names(lis))
```

---

Or use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(c(lis, list(df)))[, .(split(.SD, city))]$V1
```

Or a slightly more efficient, will be with `split`

```
Map(rbind, lis, split(df, df$city)[names(lis)])
```